# Apple Firebase Authentication automatically logged in

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

our Flutter app is acting weird on some iOS devices. When we install the app first time and run, it acts like it is already logged in. Looks like someone already entered email/password and passed Firebase authentication successfully (log in) and now app treats that user like it already has a session (logged in background) but that is obviously very wrong, because user never had a chance to log in.

Why does Apple do that sometimes, to treat freshly installed app like it has already been logged in at some point? I feel like it has something with TestFlight.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Two options that come to mind...

Has the same user been logged in to the same app on another device by any chance? If so, did you enable [sharing of credentials across devices through iCloud](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/6924)?

If that's not it, did the user already sign in to another app in the same group and did you enable [cross-app authentication with shared Apple Keychain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/single-sign-on)